# File input dialog not shown with CrossWalk project

Tags: cordova, crosswalk

I've built a simple (content entirely remote) app with CrossWalk. In the app there is a `<input type="file">` element for uploading photos. But the usual dialog for selecting photo album doesn't show up.

To experiment, I made a minimum app with the same tag in `index.html` and it works. So I'm lost.

My app has a `index.js` that navigate to an external web site like this:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    // window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
    ref = window.open('http://foo.com', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no,hardwareback=no');
},
```

In the real page, there is a similar input box but when tapping on it, nothing happens.

ps. I'm using `plupload`. Not sure if it has anything to do with it.

Comment: when you do the window.open you use inAppBrowser plugin, that uses the default webview, not the crosswalk webview.